# Rails mailer preview shows correctly but undefinted method error occurs when sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, action, mailer

I'm pretty new to rails and have been following a few tutorials for sending email with Action Mailer. The application I am working on consists of adding repair tickets and sending an email notification to the customer when a button is clicked. I have been able to send emails when creating a new repair ticket but have run into issues when trying to send the email via a button. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions regarding this issue.

Rails 4.2.0
Ruby 2.1.5
Ubuntu 14.0.4
PostgreSQL

I confirmed that my mail server settings were correct by calling my mail function from the create method in repair_tickets.rb when a new repair ticket is saved. I would like this same email notification sent when I click a button.

```
    def create
      @repair_ticket = RepairTicket.new(repair_ticket_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @repair_ticket.save
    ExampleMailer.sample_email(@repair_ticket.customer.email).deliver_now

    format.html { redirect_to @repair_ticket, notice: 'Repair ticket was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @repair_ticket }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @repair_ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Currently I can successfully view the HTML and plain-text emails in the browser via the preview page. (rails/mailers/example_mailer/sample_mail_preview) However, when I click my "Email Customer" button I receive the following error message.

```
NoMethodError in RepairTicketsController#send_order_mail
undefined method `customer' for nil:NilClass

 def send_order_mail
ExampleMailer.sample_email(@repair_ticket.customer.email).deliver_now

end
# GET /repair_tickets/1 

Rails.root: /home/vmann/newiab/iab-v2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/repair_tickets_controller.rb:13:in `send_order_mail'
```

Email Model mailers/example_mailer.rb

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "default@gmail.com"

def sample_email(customer)
  @customer = customer
  mail(to: @customer, subject: 'Sample Email')
 end
end
```

repair_tickets_controller.rb

```
def send_order_mail
  ExampleMailer.sample_email(@repair_ticket.customer.email).deliver_now
end
```

routes.rb

```
 get :send_order_mail, to: 'repair_tickets#send_order_mail', as: :send_order_mail
```

repair_tickets\show.html.erb (where I have my button located)

```
<%= link_to 'Email Customer', send_order_mail_path , class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: Well, what's `@repair_ticket` in the controller?

Comment: The intention was to use it to pull information through customer. In this case I wanted to pull email from customer through @repair_ticket. My repair ticket model contains "belongs_to :customer" and my customer model contains "has_many :repair_tickets" to facilitate this. Am I not approaching this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

repair_tickets_controller.rb

```
def send_order_mail
  ExampleMailer.sample_email(@repair_ticket.customer.email).deliver_now
end
```

The error message is saying @repair_ticket == nil, essentially you have not yet assigned a value to it, which needs to happen on the first line of the send_order_mail method. To do this, you will need to send an id with the url generated and sent by your button, which is then accessed by the controller to create the repair_ticket. For example, @repair_ticket = RepairTicket.find(params[:id]).